# Displaced multidimensional arrays in common lisp

Tags: multidimensional-array, common-lisp

So I have some code that needs a subset of a multidimensional array in such a way that it works a bit more like taking a subsection of a matrix, ideally it would work like a displaced array.

So let's say I have something that looks like this

```
(defvar *a* (make-array '(3 3) :initial-contents 
   '((1 2 3) (2 3 1) (3 1 2))
```

And I want it to be accessible with an array `*b*`

```
(defvar *b* (make-array '(2 2) :displaced-to *a* :displaced-index-offset 
    (array-major-row-index *a* '(1 1)))
```

Such that `*b*` will point to

```
 #2a((3 1) (1 2))
```

instead of

```
 #2a((3 1) (3 1))
```

I've already written myself a multidimensional slice function that copies the parts of the array I want, but it would be ideal to not need to copy back and forth manually, is there any solution that works like this in vanilla common lisp?

I understand that the way that displaced multidimensional arrays work in a way that coheres directly with `(array-major-row-index)` (namely that `#2a((1 2 3) (2 3 4))` has row indices `(0 1 2 3 4 5)` and therefore the displaced array at `'(1 0)` of dimensions `'(2 2)` will point to `#2a((2 3) (2 3))`, so I need to wrap the new array such that it refers to specific places in the old one, but so far I don't know how to capture such a reference.

I'm not entirely sure that it is possible to get pointers to places in the array, so I would appreciate if that could be cleared up.

Comment: You can't do this with built in arrays and furthermore displaced arrays tend to not perform well in most implementations (i.e. SBCL). A solution would be to keep all your data in a large vector and simply keep small objects containing dimensions and strides (i.e. Enough information to represent the kind of subsets you would want such that you can easily convert a (multidimensional) index into the correct index into the vector) This is possible but you need to write your own functions for taking subsets (or transposing or whatever) and your own function and setf-expander for access.

Comment: @DanRobertson Thanks, this is another good reason to just copy in and out of the arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multidimensional arrays are stored in memory as a one-dimensional array in row-major order. That is, `#2a((1 2 3) (2 3 1) (3 1 2))` is actually the same as `#(1 2 3 2 3 1 3 1 2)`.

```
CL-USER> (let ((a (make-array '(3 3) :initial-contents 
                              '((1 2 3) (2 3 1) (3 1 2)))))
           (make-array 9 :displaced-to a))
#(1 2 3 2 3 1 3 1 2)
```

A displaced array is a contiguous subset of the actual array (sharing memory with it). Your desired `*B*` would not be contiguous, since it would have to arbitrarily jump over the last `3` in the array.

```
           *B*
          /   \
        ---   ---
1 2 3 2 3 1 3 1 2
```

You would have to either include the skipped over `3` in the displaced array, or use two separate displaced arrays.

Comment: Thanks, I suspect that I will just write a function or something to copy the changed array slice back into it's former place.

Answer (score 4):

You can't directly do it, but FYI there used to be support for this in Symbolics Lisp Machines.

From [Kent Pitman](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.lisp/QfLbsBI-WBc/20d8jxXFYfMJ):

> What was new with the LispM, and which did not carry into CL (perhaps
>   because of the lack of microcode assist for speed) was conformally
>   displaced arrays (I think you said :displaced-conformally t, or some
>   such) in which case you got a displaced region of the original square
>   (cube, etc) rather than a region of the linearized storage.  This was
>   useful for displacing to screen memory, especially since the LispM
>   used DMA (direct memory access) display from a raster array that was,
>   I think, specially known by the screen to mean "this array's memor IS
>   the screen" and doing a SETF of AREF into that special array made
>   something appear on the screen.  All windows had conformally displaced
>   indirect arrays that represented their part of the screen.

As pointed out by Rainer Joswig, there is [a video on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4-YnLpLgtk&t=10m20s), from Kalman Reti, demonstrating conformally displaced arrays. It might be possible for implementations to provide support for this, but I don't know if any current one provides such displaced arrays. But other answers are fine suggesting alternatives.

Comment: The Symbolics Lisp Machine's conformally displaced arrays is actually demonstrated by Kalman Reti in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4-YnLpLgtk starting at 10:20.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Thanks. Just in case you don't know, you can specify an offset in Youtube videos with `&t=__m__s` (or use http://youtubetime.com).

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the answer of jkiiski you cannot obtain directly what you want, but you could “approximate” such result by using array of arrays, instead of multi-dimensional arrays.

For instance:

```
(defvar *a* (make-array 3 :initial-contents '(#(1 2 3) #(2 3 1) #(3 1 2))))
```

and then `*b*` could be defined as an array whose elements are arrays displaced on the appropriate arrays of `*a*`:

```
(defvar *b* 
  (make-array 2 :initial-contents
    (loop for row from 1 to 2
       collect (make-array 2 :displaced-to (aref *a1* row) :displaced-index-offset 1))))
```

The main difference with respect to the multi-dimensional arrays is that instead of using:

```
(aref *b* 1 1)
```

you should use:

```
(aref (aref *b* 1) 1)  ; => produces 2 for the example above
```

And of course you could define macros or reader macros to simplify this notation.

Comment: You could also keep `*A*` two-dimensional and change the collect to something like `(make-array 2 :displaced-to *a* :displaced-index-offset (1+ (* row 3)))`

Comment: I considered this, but I really don't want to have to do the nested aref calls, it also doesn't let me work with any of the array functions that provide support for multidimensional arrays, which means that my matrix code would have to be rewritten, and more or less, I'd rather not do that.